# Get bean class from composite component

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, facelets, composite-component

I have composite component:

```
<my:component value="#{bean.property1.property2}/>
```

From composite component I need to get class of `bean.property1` to read its annotations. 
I do it by the following code:

```
ValueExpression valueExpression = expressionFactory.createValueExpression(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext(),
                        "#{bean.property1}", Object.class);
Object bean = valueExpression.getValue(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext());
Class<?> beanClass = bean.getClass();
```

This works well but if I use `my:component` from a facelet and pass `bean` as a parameter via `ui:param` this does not work because `bean` can't be resolved.

Probably I should use `FaceletContext` as `ELContext` instead of `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getELContext()`:

```
FaceletContext faceletElContext = (FaceletContext) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getAttributes()
                    .get("javax.faces.FACELET_CONTEXT");
```

But this doesn't work on `RENDER_RESPONSE` phase (from `encodeBegin` method). It returns last used ELContext instead of actual context (I am not surprised :) ).

The goal is to get class of `#{bean.property1}` from `my:component`. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is easy with `RichFaces`:

```
    ValueExpressionAnalayser analyser = new ValueExpressionAnalayserImpl();
    ValueDescriptor valueDescriptor = analyser.getPropertyDescriptor(context, valueExpression);
    Class<?> beanClass = valueDescriptor.getBeanType();
```

This is ok for me.

Also there is `ValueExpressionAnalayzer` in `javax.faces.validator` package but it is package private and can't be used.

Comment: JSF's own `ValueExpressionAnalayzer` is a package-private class and thus unfortunately not publicly useable. OmniFaces has also an `org.omnifaces.el.ExpressionInspector` for the purpose. It even supports extracting method parameters from the EL expression (used in a.o. `<o:graphicImage>`).

Comment: @BalusC You are right regarding package private. I've edited my answer. I should take a look at OmniFaces. Does it get on with RichFaces?

Comment: Several OmniFaces artifacts have been tested with RF 4.5. At least, it should just fine run side by side, like as with PrimeFaces. OmniFaces is intented to be compatible with any JSF component library. If you found any compatibility issues with latest RF versions, please by all means report an [issue](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues).

Answer (score 0):

You could pass the bean as a parameter to the component.

1) Declare the attribute in the component interface file(if you are using composite component):

```
<cc:interface componentType="myComponentClass">
    <cc:attribute name="myBean" preferred="true"/>
    ..others attributes
<cc:interface>
```

2) Implement the respective getter and setter for "myBean" attribute in the component class(myComponentClass)

```java
protected enum PropertyKeys {
    myBean;

    String toString;

    PropertyKeys(String toString) {
        this.toString = toString;
    }

    PropertyKeys() {}

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ((this.toString != null) ? this.toString : super.toString());
    }
}
public YourBeanClass getMyBean() {
    return (YourBeanClass) getStateHelper().eval(PropertyKeys.myBean,   null);
}
public void setMyBean(YourBeanClass myBean) {
    getStateHelper().put(PropertyKeys.myBean, myBean);
}
```

3) Set the attribute on you jsf page:

```html
<my:component myBean="#{bean}"/>
```

4) In the component's render class cast the UIComponent to myComponentClass.

```java
@Override
public void encodeBegin(FacesContext pContext, UIComponent pComponent)
    throws IOException {
    myComponentClass myComponent = (myComponentClass) pComponent;
    myComponent.getYourAttribute();
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately I can't add new attribute to the existing component. There are quite a lot of pages that use this component and that I should not change.